# $H$ be hilbert space and $f:H^2\to\Bbb{C}$ such that $|f(h,k)|\le \lVert h\rVert\lVert k\rVert$ and it is linear in $h$ and antilinear in $k$. Show..

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$  be hilbert space and $f:H^2\to\Bbb{C}$ be a map such that $|f(h,k)|\le \lVert h\rVert\lVert k\rVert$ and it is linear in $h$ and anti-linear in $k$. Show that there exists $T\in B(H)$ such that $f(h,k)=\langle Th,k\rangle\ \forall h,k\in H$

Let $\{e_i\}$ be a orthonomal basis of $H$ (may not be countable). Then I define $$T(h)=\sum\limits_i f(h,e_i)e_i$$
But the problem here is I don't know whether the series $\sum\limits_i f(h,e_i)e_i$ converges in $H$ or not.

I am not getting any wayout to proceed. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any fixed $k$, $\overline {f(h,k)}$ is linear map from $H$ to $\mathbb C$ and the given inequality shows that it is also bounded. By Riesz Theorem there exists a unique $y \in H$ such that $\overline {f(h,k)}= \langle k, y \rangle$ for all $k$. Denote $y$ by $Th$. Then we have  $f(h,k)=\langle Th, k \rangle$ for all $h$ and $k$. We also have $|\langle  Th,k \rangle |\leq \|k\|$ if $\|h\|\leq 1$. This implies that $\|Th\| \leq 1$ if $\|h\| \leq 1$. So $T$ is a bounded operator with norm at most $1$.